# Is dietary fat directly stored in adipose tissue or is it immediately metabolized?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, fat-metabolism

I know that fat goes to adipose tissue and even sugar gets converted to fat and goes to adipose tissue, but what happens to fat (unsalted cow milk butter) I just ate? Will it give me energy now, or does it automatically goes to adipose tissues for future energy storage?

Comment: first come, first server mechanism: for example, if you have not eaten a single thing in 2 days, the first thing you put in your mouth will be used for energy immediately and you will feel satiated. note that since you did not die in those 2 days your body is using the energy in your adipose stores (from your physical body fat) first and only then from outside sources.

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?